# Seeking help identifying a connector

Tags: identification, connector

[image: connector]

I'm seeking help identifying a connector.  It is 4-pin, 1.25mm pin spacing, and looks similar to a JST, except that this connector is missing the slot and bar guides JST connectors have on their sides, and the tab to disengage the connector lock is different. I include a photo above of the male/female versions. (Sorry for image quality.)  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I used my [Connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_latch_w2b_conn&f=discrete_1row_latch_w2b_conn_1p2&s=Micro-Lock%20504194%20504195%20%2B%20504193) to match it to a [Molex Micro-lock](https://www.molex.com/molex/news/display_news.jsp?channel=New&channelId=-8&oid=1120)

- Male PCB header: [Molex 5041950470](https://www.digikey.ee/en/products/detail/molex/5041950470/4879345)
- Female housing: [Molex 5041930400](https://www.digikey.ee/en/products/detail/molex/5041930400/4879321)

[image: Molex Micro-lock] {Source: Digikey, above links}

Comment: Thanks so much Davide Andrea for the part ID and the Connector Identification Utility reference!